AWS DMS Data Migration Issue: Persistent Failure to Load Data for Specific Table, Escalating Errors on Restart
I'm facing a persistent issue with AWS DMS where one of my tables fails to load data during migration. I’m using the latest version of AWS DMS, but I receive the error message: "Command failed to load data with exit error code 0 and exitwhy 1."
Furthermore, upon restarting the migration task, almost all tables fail with the following error:
"Failed to wait for previous run; Failed to load data from CSV file.; Handling End of table 'public'.'table' loading failed by subtask 1 thread 1."
I’m unsure why this specific table is failing consistently, and restarting the task seems to escalate the issue across multiple tables.
I have attempted two migration strategies using AWS DMS: Full Load and Full Load CDC (Change Data Capture). However, both approaches encountered persistent issues.
With Full Load + CDC, the task fails after some time with the following error: "Last Error Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [reptask/replicationtask.c:2673] [1022502] Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE."
To mitigate these issues, I have taken the following steps:

Increased Transaction Timeout: I raised the default transaction timeout to 1200.

Adjusted Data Type Mapping: I modified numeric data type mappings to increase precision and scale.


Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and the specific table continues to fail during data migration.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I encountered an issue while using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) to migrate data from a PostgreSQL Aurora RDS cluster. The migration failed with the error message "Command failed to load data with exit error code 1". After enabling CloudWatch Logs for my PostgreSQL Aurora RDS cluster, I discovered that DMS was attempting to convert a column with an array data type into varchar during the migration process. This conversion was unsupported by DMS, leading to the migration failure.
To resolve this issue, I utilized a table transformation rule in DMS. Specifically, I changed the data type of the problematic column from array to CLOB (Character Large Object). This adjustment allowed DMS to handle the data properly during migration, thereby resolving the error.
Enabling CloudWatch Logs was crucial in pinpointing the data type mismatch and guiding me towards the appropriate transformation solution. For anyone facing similar issues with DMS, I recommend leveraging table transformation rules to align data types between your source and target databases effectively.
